# rounding a float field in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a field lets call that `Rate`.  It is a `float` in the table. When is comes into the C# code into the property it is a `decimal`.
What I need to do in my code is, if the value comes in with more than 4 decimals
I need to round.  So for example if the value is `0.44544` it needs to
be `0.4454`.  If it is `0.44546` then it should round to
`0.4455`.  IT should always be 4 decimal places.
Nothing is working.  I am getting extra zeros in front like this: `0.004454`.
Can someone help me with the correct code?

Comment: Can you show your incorrect code?

Comment: I have tried 20 different things but 1 is:rounded = Convert.ToDecimal(ol.MutationRate

Answer (score 1):

Use Math.Round:

```
decimal a = 1.565554M;

Math.Round(a, 4)
```

Comment: I forgot about the M.  But my field will not be hard coded.  How do I get the M in a field?  My code will need to be like this:                                       decimal a = rate;

Comment: @Chris The M is only needed for literal values to let the compiler know what numerical type it is.

Comment: Thanks.  I just realized that the code is not the rounding it's just coming in wrong to start with.

Answer (score 0):

How about `decimal.Round(0.44544M,4)` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6be1edhb(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)